# Global object declaration in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, declaration

How to declare objects globally in *kotlin* like in java  `TextView tv;`.

Or any method to call the same variable in different methods/functions.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.texfirst) as TextView 

    textView.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Welcome to Kotlin ! $abc "+textView.text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    myFunction(textView)
}

fun myFunction(mtextv : TextView) {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"This is  new  $abc "+mtextv.text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

See the above code I've separate function with parameter of `TextView`. I want the `TextView` object at second function. My question is: Is it possible to call function without parameter and am I able to get `TextView` object at `myFunction()`.

Learning kotlin in android studio. Hope question is clear .

Comment: What do you mean with "globally"? Your given code matches `var tv: TextView` in Kotlin and you can use it at the same position you do in your Java code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The one you are mentioning is [class property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#declaring-properties).

For your case, you need to declare a `TextView` in an `Activity` class and do the assignment by calling `findViewById()` in `onCreate()`.

```
class YourActivity {

    lateinit var textView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        textView = findViewById(R.id.texfirst) as TextView
        //implementation
    }

    fun myFunction() {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "This is  new $abc " + textView.text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. You may also take a look at some examples [here](https://github.com/antoniolg/Kotlin-for-Android-Developers).