# Mock a "global" property in Kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

Is there a way to change the return value of the property accessor called when running unit tests? Like mocking the result of the property `settingsState`?

I am learning to create unit tests. What that class makes is to bring stored data into the program, this data is given in a visual form. In my test, I want to define what is going on there because the window won't open there.

```
// top-level declaration outside class
val settingsState: ApplicationSettingsState
    get() = ServiceManager.getService(ApplicationSettingsState::class.java)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global object declaration in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751263/global-object-declaration-in-kotlin)

Comment: @UmairMubeen No, that seems unrelated.  This is about creating test mocks.

Comment: What is `@State` and `PersistentStateComponent` and all that stuff? Is that even relevant?

Comment: @MichaelPiefel is to show where is the var. (Outside the class) "In a global state".

Comment: Since Kotlin allows nested classes, this does not really show that we are at top-level here.

Answer (score 2):

`settingsState` is not a variable. It is a property.

I am not aware of any way to mock global properties (or global functions). The way mocking works is to cleverly create an object that looks a bit like the object to mock from the outside, but behaves differently on the inside. In the absence of an object to mock, there is no way to mock.

That said, on the bytecode level there are no global variables, properties, whatever. They are all wrapped into classes, because the JVM likes it that way. Some clever bytecode manipulation might be able to achieve some effect – but not MockK.

You can mock the property if you have a mocked object. To paraphrase the documentation:

```
val mock = mockk(Bus())
every { mock getProperty "speed" } returns 33
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You want to mock a property that is declared at top-level. Top-level code in a given Kotlin file `MyFile.kt` is actually compiled to be inside the class `MyFileKt`. Let's say we have following Kotlin file named `MyFile.kt`:

```
package foo

val bar = "some value"
```

If we compile this file to JVM bytecode and then decompile the result to Java, we get a Java class that looks similar to this:

```
package foo;

public final class MyFileKt {
   private static final String bar = "some value";

   public static final String getBar() {
      return bar;
   }
}
```

As you can see, our top-level val we defined earlier is actually translated to a static field with associated getter in the class `MyFileKt`.

---

TLDR; Getting back to our original problem, all you need to do is statically mock this field:

```
mockkStatic("foo.MyFileKt") // Fully-qualified name of the generated class
every { bar } returns "some other test value" // Define what our top-level property should return
```

The same also works for top-level functions, of course.